# Form to edit simple website template not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have only used software like Adobe Muse in the past so I am quite new to coding, but I think I have the basics down.

I am trying to create a form that will alter the content on a template site that will be duplicated.

I created the form:

```
<form class="pure-form" id="Builder" method="POST" action="scripts\build.php">
<fieldset class="pure-group">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" placeholder="Store Name" name="Name">
    <textarea class="pure-input-1" placeholder="Description" name="Description"></textarea>
    <textarea class="pure-input-1" placeholder="About Paragraph" name="About"></textarea>
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" placeholder="Store Address" name="Address">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" placeholder="Contact Number" name="Number">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" placeholder="Email Address" name="Email">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" placeholder="Tumblr Username" name="username">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" placeholder="Unique ID" name="unique">

     <button name="btnbuild" type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1 pure-button-primary">Create Website</button>
</fieldset>
```

The form seems to be functioning alright.

I created a PHP file to get the data from this form:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["Name"];
$descrip = $_POST["Description"];
$about = $_POST["About"];
$address = $_POST["Address"];
$number = $_POST["Number"];
$email = $_POST["Email"];
$username = $_POST["Username"];
$unique = $_POST["Unique"];

?>
```

I am not sure about the code for the images, but the variables should work alright.

In my index.html I used the following method to find and replace the strings that need to be replaced on the page.

```
 <head>
<script> 
      window.onload = function() {
         <?php include 'build.php'; ?>;
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("EHNAME", "<?php echo $name; ?>");
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("EHDESCRIPTION", "<?php echo $descrip; ?>");
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("EHABOUT", "<?php echo $about; ?>");
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("EHADDRESS", "<?php echo $address; ?>");
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("EHNUMBER", "<?php echo $number; ?>");
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("EHEMAIL", "<?php echo $email; ?>");
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("EHUNIQUEID", "<?php echo $unique; ?>");
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("EHUSERNAME", "<?php echo $username; ?>");
      document.title = name; }
</script> 
</head>
```

The problem is that it doesn't update the strings at all.

Any help to figure this out would be appreciated.

Comment: So what's the actual problem? What's your question?

Comment: I don't know if all the code you put here is copied, but you do have a error in the second code block. It should be `$number` instead of `number`

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited. For some reason the text on the site does not update at all.

And I must have erased the $ symbol by accident when I pasted in the code.

Comment: why don't you just inject the values directly into the right place in the markup by echoing them using PHP in the correct location, rather than this indirect method via javascript? You would need to make your page index.php though instead of index.html. Unless you've remapped your server file extensions a .html file will not execute any PHP code.

Comment: I got it working by having the form save the strings to txt files, making the page index.php, then reading from the txt files using `<?php include('scripts/name.txt') ?>` in the paragraph tags that I wanted to replace.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, your initial form post the data to: `scripts\build.php` and later you are trying to get this data in another page `index.html`, this seems to be to problem.

Even if you import the `build.php` in the `index.html` file, this is another request, so the posted data to the `build` is already gone. You can solve this problem making the post directly to the `index` or persisting the data (in the session, for example, or database) and retrieving it in the `index.html` file.